# Data reference in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two model calss user and product and i have common property productId. i want fetch the user data from Mongodb. I want to fetch user coreesponding to the product under him which should be displayed.

user model

public class User : Product
    {

```
    [BsonId] 
    public string GuId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }


    public  string ProductId { get; set; }


}
```

product model

public class Product
    {

```
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public string  ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And my application layer has below code:-

```
   public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        // var users = new User();
        IList<User> itemCollection = new List<User>();
        var itemIdList = new List<string>();
        itemCollection = _users.Include<User>.Load(itemIdList.ToArray())

                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdatedDate).ToList();

       // var itemCollection = _users.Load<User>(itemIdList.ToArray());

        this.LoadItemStatusDefinitions(itemCollection);

        var users = _users.
                         FindAll().
                         SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("createdate"));

        return users;
    }

    private void LoadItemStatusDefinitions(IEnumerable<User> items)
    {
        // iterates through each items in the collection.
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // check whether status definition is already assigned to the item 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ProductId))
            {
                // loading the status definition associated with each item
                var statusDefinition = _users.Load<Product>(item.ProductId);
                if (statusDefinition != null)
                {
                    // assign the status definition to the item.
                    item.ProductId = statusDefinition;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to do that in a single fetch, you can't. You'd need to do two findOne calls. Or, embed all the data in a single document.

Answer (score 1):

Your model looks like it is designed with a relational database in mind.  The [MongoDB site](http://www.mongodb.org/) has a good resource on [schema design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/).  It's definitely a different mindset trying to design a good document schema for MongoDB.  Don't be afraid to denormalize your data.

One possible schema might be:

```
{
    GuID: "",
    Name: "",
    EMailAddress: "",
    Product: {
        Id: 0,
        ProductId: "",
        Name: ""
    }
}
```

It's unclear whether you would need both id fields inside the product subdocument.